# Given two binary strings, return their sum (also a binary string)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone help me out with my code. It works perfectly but I am being told not to use inputs as when they perform add_binary(1,1) it will ignore those values and ask for your own inputs. which I find to be so much better lol. I honestly put this code together using the little knowledge I have and the information I gathered online. So if someone could help with a suggestion on how I could modify my code to get it to work without the manual inputs I would appreciate it! Thanks

---

```
def add_binary(a, b):

    while True:
        try:
           a = int(input('1st Binary: '), 2)
            except ValueError:
            print('not valid try again')
            continue
        try:
            b = int(input('2nd Binary: '), 2)
        except ValueError:
            print('not valid try again')
            continue
        else:
            result = (bin(a + b)[2:])
            print(result)
        break
    return result


add_binary(1,1)
```

Comment: I am confused. Are you just trying to add 1 and 1 together or am I missing something?

Comment: In your question you have _"two binary strings"_ but in your code you have two numbers. I think your task is to manually add the numbers digit by digit without conversion.

Comment: You should move the loop and the input-taking outside of the function and only do the conversion from and to binary and the adding inside the function.

Comment: got it to work thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

What they're saying is that your `add_binary` always needs to add its parameters and not ask for input directly.  The `input` calls need to be outside the function.  I assume they're doing this so that can evaluate your function by calling it using some testing framework.

```
def add_binary(a,b):
    return bin(a+b)[2:]

def main():
    a = int(input('1st Binary: '),2)
    b = int(input('2nd binary: '),2)
    result = add_binary(a,b)
    print( result )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```